# Couple of questions HTML

Tags: html

To redefine a general look for an entire HTML tag, what would be the proper selector? Would it be a class, head or id?

Also, not sure which attribute that is used for defining an inline style in HTML? class, font, type, input?

Finally, if I wanted to add a width attribute into a specific item within the html code, would it be: `width="10"` or `width:"10"`.

Thanks

Comment: I think the answer is "none of the above" for each question.

Comment: Good luck with your learning experience. Sit down with some good tutorials and go through them real slow.

Comment: What do you mean by "an entire HTML tag"?  Do you mean the `<html>` tag, or do you just mean *any* tag?  You're asking for "proper selector", so I assume you mean in CSS.  You can use either class, or id (or the type of tag, eg. `p`) depending on what you want to do.  "head" is not a selector (ok, it is, it selects the `<head>` tag, but that's not very useful).  For inline styles, it's *none* of the things you listed.  And for the width, use (inline) styles, the `width` attribute is deprecated.

Comment: Also, the way this question is worded, it looks like it was copied & pasted from an assignment or tutorial or something...

Answer (score 1):

**To redefine a general look for an entire HTML tag, what would be the proper selector? Would it be a class, head or id?**
-> To redefine a general look of a tag for the entire page you just need to use the tag name, for example: if you want to change the anchor tag to not have an underline for the entire page you just type this,

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And if you want to change everything inside a particular tag you could do something like

```
div * {
    padding: auto;
}
```

**Also, not sure which attribute that is used for defining an inline style in HTML? class, font, type, input?**
-> As of now it is a good practice not to do inline styling frequently in your code, but if you have to you could style 'almost' all the tags which follow HTML5 syntax. To do that you could write something like this:

```
<div style="width:200px"><span>Some text here</span></div>
```

**Finally, if I wanted to add a width attribute into a specific item within the html code, would it be: width="10" or width:"10".**
-> For styling anywhere and anything you have to use `property : value;` this syntax, except in javascript. For javascript you have to follow these steps: [clickable link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To style an html tag, you just use the tag as a reference:

```
p {
 color: red;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

Inline HTML styling is done with the `style` attribute, but is **not recommended**.

```
<h1 style="color:blue">This is a Blue Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

To style a tag in general, you wouldn't need to use id, class, or head.

Say you wanted to style all 'p' elements, in CSS you would put:

p {
   Property:Value
}

If you wanted to specify an elements width within the HTML code the correct way would be:

width="10" (Within an elements tags of course)

Answer (score 0):

```css
img{
 width="100px" 
} 
.image{
 width="100px" 
}
#image{
 width="100px" 
}
```

```html
<img src="" width="100px" />

<img src=""/>


<img src="" class="image" />


<img id="image" src=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to define a general look for the whole of the webpage that you wish to create, you can type the body and then define it accordingly.
For example

```
 body{
 padding:20px;
 color: blue;
 }
```

This will define the styling for all the elements under the body tag.
An alternate way for this is:

```
 *{
 padding:20px;
 }
```

By using a Universal selector, you can automatically select all the elements and apply them to the style.

Coming to your last question,
if you are using Inline CSS, you can use both the ways that you have mentioned-
"width=200"and "width:200;"

But if you are directly applying in a tag or under style tag:

```
 <img src="" width=" ">
```

This is the apt way of doing so.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

A unique selector is the id.
the class selector is for more than one tag. You use it if you would have that two tags are viewed in the same way. (from your css file)
inline styles:

```
<p style="border: 1px solid #000000">Hello World</p>
```

Last que: width="100px" for example:

```
<img src="pics/pic1.jpg" width="100px" />
```

The Tag "html" is "only for defining that here starts the document"

You have to style "each" tag (p,div,h1,h2,span,....)

http://de.selfhtml.org/css/